# How to instantiate ViewModel that extends AndroidViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, abstract-class, instantiation

I'm following a tutorial where a ViewModel extends an abstract class in order to use coroutines, this is the class that extends:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application), CoroutineScope {
private val job =  Job()

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    job.cancel()
}}
```

And this is the ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel(application: Application) : BaseViewModel(application) {}
```

So in MainActivity I'm trying to instantiate the class like this:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ViewModel::class.java]}
```

In the tutorial the guy perfectly does this but when I try to run the application it throws me an exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.name.nameapp.main.viewmodel.ViewModel
```

I feel like I'm missing something can you guys point what it is, if you need more information I'll gladly post it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ViewModel` is child of `AndroidViewModel` which requires an `Application` object. So you will have to provide the `Factory` class in order to instantiate the `ViewModel`. Like so:

```kotlin
val viewModelProvider = ViewModelProvider(
     this, 
     ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application)
)
viewModel = viewModelProvider[MainViewModel::class.java]
```

If you are using the [fragment library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment) from Jetpack

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
```

You can use property delegation like so:

```kotlin
val viewModel: ViewModel by viewModels()
```